# Equal vertical spacing in linear layout not working

Tags: android

Running the below code in ANDROID studio is not giving me the desired result: Please help? I would like the 3 TextViews to be equally spaced out vertically in the screen of the device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Debanshu"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Chakraborty"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Voltas"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: . Thanks to all. Working now. Have just started learning.

Comment: With a screenshot would be easier to get what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this (added gravity just for the fun of it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Debanshu"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Chakraborty"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Voltas"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you `LinearLayout` height equal to `wrap_content` its working but as height wrapping view you are not getting desired view

try below making `LinearLayout` height equal to `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Debanshu"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Chakraborty"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Voltas"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this its work for me

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Debanshu"
    android:background="#ffa905"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chakraborty"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Voltas"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:background="#008000"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

enjoy!!!